# rust only 10 threads at a time

Tags: multithreading, rust

I want to run test(), but only 10 times at a time. Is there a way to create a max amount of threads and wait until one thread is complete before it starts a new one.

```rs
for (i, file) in files.iter().enumerate() {
     test(i, file).await;
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for what's called a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.19.2/tokio/sync/struct.Semaphore.html)

Comment: Alternatively, the normal way is to create as many worker threads as you want / need and feed them via a common queue.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the word `thread` correctly? Given the fact that there is an `.await` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rayon` to process some data in parallel and limit the threads to be used for the processing.

*Cargo.toml*

```
[dependencies]
rayon = "1.5"
```

*main.rs*

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn test(i: usize, file: &str) {
    eprintln!("{:?}, {:?}", i , file);
}

fn main() {
    rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(10).build_global().unwrap();

    let mut files = vec![];
    for i in 0..100 {
        files.push(format!("tmp {}", i));
    }
    files.into_par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, file)| {
      test(i, file.as_str());
    });
}
```